# How to add Star rating on category page in Sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: blog, rating

I created Blog site on Sharepoint 2013. When I create post on home page I can see *star rating* but when I access to category page. It's only show post title. How to fixed this. Thanks

This is **Home Page**
[image: This is Home Page]

This is **Category Page**
[image: This is Category Page]